# Machine Learning Linear Regression Cost Function Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, linear-regression

When I see $J(\theta _{0}, \theta _{1}) = ...$ as the result of a single variable cost function in linear regression I think that it is a column vector instead of a scalar. How am I supposed to know it's a scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it is a column vector? $J$ is a function that depends on the parameters $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$. The notation $f(x,y)$ means that $f$ is a function that takes two inputs $x$ and $y$. In your case, with $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ you compute the value of $J$.

Comment: Well, okay, because when I see the entire eqn: $J(\theta _{0}, \theta _{1}) = \frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2$ then I see many more parameters than just $\theta _{0}, \theta _{1}$. I see also x and y. Why aren't they listed as parameters as well?

Comment: @KarlNicholas Because you want to express that the cost function is related to the parameters of the model, not to the data.

Comment: Okay, I'm reading about parameters now, sorry about the newb question and thanks.

Comment: @KarlNicholas don't worry. It's true that sometimes the notation used is confusing.